# How to edit a tiff aerial image in ArcMap 10.3

Tags: shapefile, convert, arcgis-10.3, geotiff-tiff

(beginner with arcmap)

I have aerial images in tiff format and I need to edit them in order to draw polygons on them.

When trying to edit them I get a message that says that there are no layers editable.

I guess I need to convert the tiff layers I have in order to be able to edit them; but how do I convert them? to what do I convert them?

Comment: If you want to draw polygons, you first need to create empty polygons in arccatalog. You can't edit a raster (tiff file).

Comment: Tiff, Jpeg or any formats like those are raster you can't edit raster in arcgis, If you want draw a polygon first of all create new shape file(polygon type) and then edit shape file by editor tool in ArcMap and draw your polygon on polygon shape file.

Comment: Here iyou'll find a tutorial for Basic Digitization in ArcGIS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6dY3x-5qX6U

Comment: If you don't know  how to create a shapefile please refer to below link this is for Arcgis 10.2.2 but It's available method for all ArcGIS10.x series. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005600000004000000

Answer (score 3):

Marta, you would not edit your tiff images to draw polygons on them.  Your tiff's are Raster datasets. Polygons are Vector datasets.  You are not able to store Rasters and Vectors within the same file.

What you need to do is create a new empty vector dataset to hold your polygons (such as a shapefile or a featureclass).  You can then draw your polygons over your raster.

If you're a beginner, it might be worth taking some time to work through this [basic introductory tutorial on editing](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Introduction_to_the_Editing_tutorial/01m600000020000000/).